# How to correctly print the result of matrices multiplication in different cases?

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication

I'm making a program that multiplies 3 matrices and print the outcome. The program can input several cases of multiplication and each case can determined their own number of NxN matrix (n). However, if I input 2 cases, first with n=2 and second with  n=3, the output of the first case will have a 3x3 matrix with row 3 and column 3 only have 0s. How do I fix this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int t, n, i, j, k, l, a[50][50][10], b[50][50][10], c[50][50][10], d[50][50][10], e[50][50][10];
    
    scanf ("%d", &t);
    
    for (l=1; l<=t; l++){
        
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    // matrix a
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", & a[i][j][l]);
        }
    }
    
    // matrix b
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", & b[i][j][l]);
        }
    }
    
    // matrix c
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", & c[i][j][l]);
        }
    }
    
    //Multiplication
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            d[i][j][l] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                d[i][j][l] += a[i][k][l] * b[k][j][l];
                
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            e[i][j][l] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                e[i][j][l] += d[i][k][l] * c[k][j][l];
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    }
    
     //Printing the product
    for (l=1; l<=t; l++){
        
    printf ("Case #%d:\n", l);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", e[i][j][l]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    }
    
    return 0;

}
```

[image]
This is the expected output.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the lack of indexing but it looks like your input loop completes before the print loops starts. This will cause a problem because the `n` in the print loop will have what ever value was last used in the input loop. So both output loops will assume a 3x3 matrix. You will either need to store the `n` values or delete the closing bracket of the input loop and the first `for` statementment in the print loop.

Comment: Edit your post to provide a [mre], including the exact text of sample input that reproduces the problem, the exact text of the observed output, and the exact text of the desired output.